# How to limit the text length of each cell in the material react table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

A regular table like this

```
<MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={emailResults}
  enableColumnFilters={false}
  enableMultiRowSelection={false}
  onRowSelectionChange={setRowSelection}
>
```

I dont want to modify emailResults the underlying data structure because this is more of a presentation logic thing and I need the full length data intact.

Answer (score 1):

Beside from what Joel has answered, you can also limit the cell width by using CSS (column width remains intact).

You need to modify the `column` object by adding a `Cell` option which you would use to custom render the data cells.

```
const columns = useMemo(

() => [
  {
    accessorKey: 'firstName',
    header: 'First Name',
    Cell: ({ cell }) => {
      return <Box sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: "green",
        width: "120px",
        overflow: "hidden"
      }}>{cell.getValue()}</Box>;
    },
  },
```

ref- [docs](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/data-columns#custom-cell-render)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    field: 'emailBody',
    headerName: 'Email Body',
    headerAlign: 'center',
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<any>) => params.row.emailBody.slice(0, YOUR_TEXT_LIMIT),
}
```

Just render cell with truncated text and keep the original text the same way